# overloading + and += operators for "Number Classes"

Tags: operator-overloading, kotlin, extension-function

I want to create extension functions for classes that encapsulate simple `Number`s. For example `DoubleProperty`. I encountered the problem, that I can't overload the `+` and the `+=` operator at the same time.

I wan't to create a behaviour, that passes following tests:

```
class DoublePropertyTest {
    lateinit var doubleProperty: DoubleProperty

    @Before
    fun initialize() {
        doubleProperty = SimpleDoubleProperty(0.1)
    }

    @Test
    fun plus() {
        val someProperty = doubleProperty + 1.5
        assertEquals(someProperty.value, 1.6, 0.001)
    }

    @Test
    fun plusAssign() {
        val someProperty = doubleProperty
        doubleProperty += 1.5 //error if + and += are overloaded

        assert(someProperty === doubleProperty) //fails with only + overloaded
        assertEquals(doubleProperty.value, 1.6, 0.001)
    }
}
```

It could be implemented using these extension functions:

```
operator fun ObservableDoubleValue.plus(number: Number): DoubleProperty 
    = SimpleDoubleProperty(get() + number.toDouble())

operator fun WritableDoubleValue.plusAssign(number: Number) 
    = set(get() + number.toDouble())
```

The problem is, that if `+` is overlodaded the `+=` can't be overloaded aswell:

```
Assignment operators ambiguity. All these functions match.
- public operator fun ObservableDoubleValue.plus(number: Number): DoubleProperty
- public operator fun WritableDoubleValue.plusAssign(number: Number): Unit
```

If I only overload the `+` operator, a new `DoubleProperty` object is returned on `+=` operations instead of the initial one.

Is there a way to work around this limitation?

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: @voddan I added a comment in the code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The strange `+=` operator in Kotlin

you can both overloading the `plus` operator and `plusAssign` operator in kotlin, but you must following the rules of kotlin to solving the strange `+=` conflicts.

> 1. introduce an **immutable structure** of the class for the `plus` operator which means any class outside the class can't edit its internal data.
> 2. introduce a **mutable structure** of the class for the `plusAssign` operator which means its internal data can be edited anywhere.

the kotlin has already done such things in the `stdlib` for the `Collection` & the `Map` classes, the [Collection#plus](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.2/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L1893-L1898) and [MutableCollection#plusAssign](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.2/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/MutableCollections.kt#L70-L72) as below:

```
operator fun <T> Collection<T>.plus(elements: Iterable<T>): List<T>
//                   ^--- immutable structure

operator fun <T> MutableCollection<in T>.plusAssign(elements: Iterable<T>)
//                   ^--- mutable structure
```

### But wait, how to solving the conflict when we using the `+=` operator?

**IF** the list is an immutable `Collection` then you must define a mutable `var` variable, then the `plus` operator is used since its internal state can't be edited. for example:

```
//         v--- define `list` with the immutable structure explicitly  
var list: List<Int> = arrayListOf(1);   //TODO: try change `var` to `val`
val addend = arrayListOf(2);
val snapshot = list;

list += addend;
//   ^--- list = list.plus(addend);
//  list = [1, 2], snapshot=[1], addend = [2]
```

**IF** the list is a mutable `MutableCollection` then you must define a immutable `val` variable, then the `plusAssign` operator is used since its internal state can be edited anywhere. for example:

```
//    v--- `list` uses the mutable structure implicitly
val list = arrayListOf(1); //TODO: try change `val` to `var`
val addend = arrayListOf(2);
val snapshot = list;

list += addend;
//   ^--- list.plusAssign(addend);
//  list = [1, 2], snapshot=[1, 2], addend = [2]
```

On the other hand, you can overloads an *operator* with diff signatures, each signature for the different **context**, and kotlin also do it, e.g: [Collection#plus](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html). for example:

```
var list = listOf<Int>();

list += 1; //list = [1];
//   ^--- list = list.plus(Integer);

list += [2,3]; //list = [1, 2, 3]
//   ^--- list = list.plus(Iterable);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your operator override implementation has two problems:

**1. inconsistent type after `plus`**

```
operator fun ObservableDoubleValue.plus(number: Number): DoubleProperty 
    = SimpleDoubleProperty(get() + number.toDouble())
```

Any `ObservableDoubleValue` instance plus a `Number`, got a `DoubleProperty` instance(or say a `SimpleDoubleProperty` instance). Let's say I have a type `ComplexDoubleProperty` implements `ObservableDoubleValue`, you will see:

```
var a = getComplexDoubleProperty()
a = a + 0.1    //compile error, WTF?

//or even
var b = SimpleDoubleProperty(0.1)
b = b + 0.1    //compile error, because b+0.1 is DoubleProperty
```

You can see this behavior makes no sense.

**2. a=a+b and a+=b should be identical**

If your implementation compiles, you will have

```
var a: DoubleProperty = SimpleDoubleProperty(0.1)  //add DoubleProperty to make it compile
var b = a
a += 0.1
println(b == a)
```

prints `true` because `+=` sets the value to the original instance. If you replace `a+=0.1` with `a=a+0.1` you will get `false` because a new instance is returned. Generally speaking, `a=a+b` and `a+=b` are not identical in this implementation.

To fix the two problems above, my suggestion is

```
operator fun SimpleDoubleProperty.plus(number: Number): SimpleDoubleProperty
        = SimpleDoubleProperty(get() + number.toDouble())
```

so you don't need to override `plusAssign`. The solution is not as general as yours, but it's correct if you only have `SimpleDoubleProperty` calculations, and I believe you do, because in your implementation, `plus` always returns a `SimpleDoubleProperty` instance.

Comment: I accept 1. but I am not content with returning a new instance of my `Property`, because that would almost completely defeat the reason to override `plus()` and `plusAssign()`. If, for example other properties are bound to a specific instance and you `plusAssign` on it, the `changeEvent` would never get fired and none of the observers would update.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overload both `+` and `+=`. Overload one of the them.

> When you write += in your code, theoretically both plus the plusAssign functions
>   can be called (see figure 7.2). If this is the case, and both functions are defined and
>   applicable, the compiler reports an error.

I copied/pasted from **Kotlin in Action** book!

Answer (score -2):

If `DoubleProperty` is your class, you can make `plus` and `plusAssign` its methods, that should resolve any ambiguity.

Comment: No, DoubleProperty is a class from the Java/JavaFX Standardlibrary.