# Augment assignment and increment are not supported for local delegated properties ans inline properties

Tags: android, kotlin

as in title:
`Augment assignment and increment are not supported for local delegated properties ans inline properties` - I get this for a following piece of code:

```
var timer by someDelegate { }
timer += someOtherValue
```

which compiled perfectly as long as half an hour ago. Cleaning the project  and resetting Android Studio did not help.

Comment: you can try to replace it with `timer = timer + someOtherValue`.

Comment: Providing more context of your problem.

Comment: I confirm it doesn't work for me ether

Comment: The should be ok because when `plusAssingned` is not defined, such an expression is converted to `timer = timer + someOtherValue

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: @voddan No. `plusAssingned` is for immutable variables if the `plus` exists. in other words, the `+=` will always use the `plus`  with a mutable variable when both `plusAssingned` and `plus` are exist. you can see here as further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558663/overloading-and-operators-for-number-classes/44562224#44562224

Comment: @holi-java of course this is what I did, thank you :) But still it bothers me, how it _just_ stopped working!

Comment: @Miha_x64 I define it in an extension function for my specific type of `activity` (a bit weird at first glance, but surprisingly very readable). Is it enough or do you need more information?

Comment: @holi-java regarding mentioned stack question, I will just look into the definition of the delegate I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because this feature is not implemented yet, it's not a bug, :). here is the source code of the [StackValue#L1815](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.3/compiler/backend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/codegen/StackValue.java#L1815) in Kotlin 1.1.3 as below:

```
if (stackValue instanceof Delegate) {
    //TODO need to support
    throwUnsupportedComplexOperation(((Delegate) stackValue).variableDescriptor);
}
```

Why does the **property** can working with `+=`, this is because the `Delegate` is wrapped by `getter`/`setter`, which means it is invisible from the client code.

Comment: Ah yeah, we saw that, but I'm still wondering why _it just stopped working_ (it worked for a week or so) - or maybe, why it worked in the first place!

Comment: @Antek maybe you used the newest version kotlin in last week.

Comment: how this could be? The version used in the project has been stable at 1.1.3-2 since 13th of July, and I don't remember any update notifications

Comment: @Antek I'm sure you can't, maybe you make it to a **property** rather than a local **variable**. the newest version kotlin also don't support that: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/backend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/codegen/StackValue.java#L1718

Comment: computers are weird (:

Comment: regarding property - I'm defining `timer` as a local variable inside extension function, I can make it an extension property. I hope I will have time to look into this possibility.